# kibanaのインストール時エラーになった

Tags: linux, macos, elasticsearch

Elastcisearchはインストール出来ました。
kibanaをインストールした時、以下のエラーが出ました。

それって、MacOSをUpgradeしないといけないってことでしょうか。
どなたか知ってる方いれば、教えていただきたいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/xxxx/Library/Logs/Homebrew/icu4c/02.make:
./formatted_string_builder.h:227:9: note: subexpression not valid in a constant expression
U_ASSERT(category <= 0xf),
^
../common/uassert.h:35:26: note: expanded from macro 'U_ASSERT'
# define U_ASSERT(exp) void()
^
./formatted_string_builder.h:240:64: note: in call to 'Field(0, 1)'
constexpr FormattedStringBuilder::Field kGeneralNumericField = {UFIELD_CATEGORY_UNDEFINED, 1};
^
3 errors generated.
*** Failed compilation command follows: ----------------------------------------------------------
clang++ -DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED= -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_HAVE_STRTOD_L=1 -DU_HAVE_XLOCALE_H=1 -I. -I../common -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -Qunused-arguments -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wglobal-constructors -fvisibility=hidden -fno-common -c -MMD -MT numfmt.d numfmt.o numfmt.ao -o numfmt.ao numfmt.cpp
--- ( rebuild with "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make VERBOSE=1 all" to show all parameters ) --------
make[1]: *** [numfmt.ao] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!

Error: You are using macOS 10.11.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience while you are running this old version.
```

Comment: `brew update` か何かのタイミングで `icu4c` のバージョンが更新され、macOS 10.11では使えないバージョンが入ってしまったようです。一番良いのはmacOSを10.13(High Sierra)以上に更新することかもしれません。 `brew info icu4c` で古いバージョンが手元に残っていれば、 `brew switch` でそのバージョンに戻すこともできるとは思いますが、それでkibanaがインストールできるかどうかはやってみないと分かりません。https://qiita.com/KyoheiG3/items/912bcc27462871487845

Answer (score 0):

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/icu4c

icu4c
C/C++ and Java libraries for Unicode and globalization

http://site.icu-project.org/home

/api/formula/icu4c.json (JSON API)

Formula code on GitHub
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/69cf71ca17a2d37a40336010376d82564287c121/Formula/icu4c.rb

```rb
  url "https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-67-1/icu4c-67_1-src.tgz"
  version "67.1"
  sha256 "94a80cd6f251a53bd2a997f6f1b5ac6653fe791dfab66e1eb0227740fb86d5dc"

  bottle do
    cellar :any
    sha256 "2d1e91b5127f66e7941790c004817c94c892725c88f84f1e4c37297fcbc0c72f" => :catalina
    sha256 "b6069459c78f18045ee922ce5cb5b235d4b479597d79c3c298d09e0de3d70794" => :mojave
    sha256 "0720bd47f020d5ca895ae79eb61623ed3c7de0d4c4f221613105f47147aec01f" => :high_sierra
  end
```

Current versions:

stable  ✅   67.1
bottle    catalina, mojave, high_sierra

現在HomebrewのFomulaに書かれているicu4cのバージョンは 67.1 であり、macOSはHigh Sierra(10.13)以上であることが要求されます。